# How to install an older version of Firefox easily?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, installation, pip, easy-install

I am an Ubuntu user and I would like to have an older version of Firefox on my system (to enable [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/) to write to my file system).

I found in Internet the sequence of steps for installation of older version. However, I would like to go a simple way (without saving archives, unpacking them and so on). Is the a command line way to do that. Something like using `easy_install` or `pip`? Can I have two version of Firefox on my system?

I am not sure but it seems to me that I need to go in the direction of virtual environments but I do not now how exactly it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/portable/files/ you can download a number of pre-built portable (meaning they don't need to be installed) Linux applications. There are also several versions of Firefox available for download.

They are built by http://portablelinuxapps.org/ who give the following procedure:

1. Download desired application. For example: `Firefox 6.0`
2. Run `chmod a+x Firefox 6.0`